# Placing Add button into UITableView header (swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, user-interface

I placed add button using viewForHeaderInSection, like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let frame: CGRect = tableView.frame
    let addButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(70, 0, 70, 70))
    addButton.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
    addButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    addButton.backgroundColor = .blue
    let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.height, frame.size.width))
    headerView.addSubview(addButton)
    addButton.addConstraints(.alignTrailingWithTrailing(of: headerView, const: 10))
    return headerView
}
```

Unfortunately, this makes my UITable view looking not so good:

[image: the button is shifted down]

How can I place add button into header section? (right to "Contacts" title).

Thank you. View hierarchy is attached.
[image]

Comment: Is your table view located *below* the "Contacts" text? Or is "Contacts" part of the table view? Please describe your view hierarchy. What is the relationship between all these views?

Comment: Thank you, I've added it into the post. My table view is placed into UITabBarController so it's a part of UITableViewController. "Contacts" is its title.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's no way to implement that in UITableViewController.

But there's another way - you can create UIViewController, make it conformed  to TableView protocols and implement there both UITableView and UIView with add button.

I did it this way:

```
final class ContactsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

   lazy var addButton = { [view = self.buttonBarView] in
    let button = UIButton()
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    button.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
    button.addConstraints(
        .alignTopWithTop(of: view),
        .alignBottomWithBottom(of: view),
        .alignTrailingWithTrailing(of: view, const: 8),
        .setAspectWidth(ratio: 1)
    )
    return button
}()

lazy var buttonBarView = { [view = self.view] in
    let barView = UIView()
    if let view {
        view.addSubview(barView)
        barView.addConstraints(
            .alignTopWithTop(of: view),
            .alignLeadingWithLeading(of: view),
            .alignWidth(with: view, mult: 1),
            .alignHeight(with: view, mult: 0.045)
        )
    }
    return barView
}()

lazy var tableView = { [view = self.view, buttonBarView = self.buttonBarView] in
    let tableView = UITableView()
    if let view {
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.addConstraints(
            .alignTopWithBottom(of: buttonBarView),
            .alignLeadingWithLeading(of: view),
            .alignWidth(with: view, mult: 1),
            .alignBottomWithBottom(of: view)
        )
    }
    return tableView
}()

// UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource stuff here..
```

It works as desired:

[image]